# Well-definedness of function computing fixed point, in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

This is related to Project Euler problem 523.

The following algorithm sorts a list:

> 1. Starting from the beginning of the list, check each pair of adjacent elements in turn.
> 2. If the elements are out of order:
>
>    1. Move the smallest element of the pair at the beginning of the list.
>    2. Restart the process from step 1.
> 3. If all pairs are in order, stop.

I am attempting (for practice) to code this up in Isabelle. I have obtained the following function definitions:

```
fun firstpos :: "nat list ⇒ nat"
where "firstpos [] = 0"
| "firstpos (x # y # xs) = (if (x > y) then 1 else (firstpos (y#xs))+1)"
| "firstpos [x] = Suc 0"
```

and

```
fun insertAtFront :: "(nat list) ⇒ (nat) ⇒ (nat list)"
where "insertAtFront l 0 = l"
| "insertAtFront l i = [hd (rev (take i l))] @ (take (i-1) l) @ (rev (take ((length l) - i) (rev l)))"
```

where `firstpos` determines the list-index of the first element which is greater than its successor in the list, and `insertAtFront` permutes the list so that the "second argument"th element is at the front.

That is, `firstPos` effectively tells us where to start doing Step 2 of the algorithm, and `insertAtFront` is step 2.1 of the algorithm.

Now, I wish to define the function which is basically the fixed point of the composition of these. In other words,

```
fun sortproc :: "nat list ⇒ nat list" 
where "sortproc l = sortproc (insertAtFront l (firstpos l + 1))"
```

It is nontrivial that this procedure ever terminates, but I can prove it mathematically: at each stage, $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^i L_{n-i}$ decreases, where $n$ is the length of list $L$.

I am a novice in Isabelle. How can I code the idea "this definition is well-defined, because of this proof" in Isabelle? The documentation seems to talk mainly about size arguments, and the size of the input isn't changing: it's always a list of the same length.

Comment: I don't know Isabelle, so I don't know how to code it, but what you need is *some* integer that decreases. So where the documentation talks about “size”, plug in sum(2^i * L(n-i)).

Comment: @Gilles Oh, of course! That's the meat of the answer. There's still some work after that (to convert the proof of termination into steps simple enough for Isabelle to understand), and I need to sort that bit out, but when I've done it I'll self-answer.

Comment: Just for the record: with method `relation` (see `isabelle doc function` Section 4 for examples) you can use arbitrary well-founded orders. When natural numbers are involved this can usually conveniently be combined with `measure :: ('a ⇒ nat) ⇒ ('a × 'a) set`. Then a termination proof looks roughly as follows: `apply (relation "measure (%x. f x)") ...` where `f` is the expression that decreases w.r.t. `x`.